# ArrayList Objects runtime inputs being treated as Strings

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add Objects to ArrayList, during static inputs, it's working fine

```
class ArrayListDemo4
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Collection cl = new ArrayList();
        cl.add(true);cl.add("Hello");cl.add(6.55f);cl.add(566);
        out.println(cl);

        for(Object o: cl)
            System.out.println(o.getClass());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
D:\COLLECTIONS>java ArrayListDemo4
[true, Hello, 6.55, 566]
class java.lang.Boolean
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Float
class java.lang.Integer
```

When I'm trying to do the same with runtime inputs, the getClass() is giving only as String. I noticed that `next()` has 2 signatures with different return types`public java.lang.String next(), public java.lang.Object next()` and generalized console input to Object

```
class ArrayListDemo3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner  input = new Scanner(in);
        List cl = new ArrayList(4);

        out.println("Enter the objects to the ArrayList:");
        for (int i =0; i < 4; i++ )
        {out.print("cl["+i+"]   =  ");  cl.add((Object)input.next());   }
        out.println(cl);

        for(Object o: cl)
        {out.println(o.getClass());}
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the objects to the ArrayList:
cl[0]   =  true
cl[1]   =  Hello
cl[2]   =  6.55f
cl[3]   =  566
[true, Hello, 6.55f, 566]
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
```

Can someone please correct/help me with - how do I get respective Object types for runtime entered values?

Comment: ? you ***ARE*** adding Strings to the ArrayList. Why does the output surprise you?

Comment: You're using a Scanner object and calling its `.next()` method -- what does the Scanner API state that this method returns?

Comment: "I noticed that next() has 2 signatures with different return typespublic java.lang.String next(), public java.lang.Object next()" where did you noticed that? Can you link us to documentation of both methods?

Comment: Link: [Scanner API .next() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : I was actually wondering if the JVM will be able to convert the inputs to corresponding Objects at `cl.add((Object)input.next())` and `getClass()` would give the output similar to the first one

Comment: @Pshemo
`javap java.util.Scanner | findstr next()` on windows pc, only difference is return type though

Comment: @SaiKiran: there is no "magic" in programming, and the JVM only knows what you give it. You are adding Strings and only Strings to the ArrayList and this is all the JVM knows. Note that Java does not use "duck typing", but rather this information is statically typed

Comment: What you see as `Object next()` comes from `E next()` declared in `Iterator` which Scanner implements and **overrides** that method to `String next()` which is only method available from Scanner.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : looks like I missed that point, was just curious when add() is able to take Objects as arguments at compilation but why not dynamically. Thanks for clarifying :), have an upvote

Comment: @Pshemo: Thank you, I should have navigated through those as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult with [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) javadoc, and you will find that [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) always returns `String`.

At the same time `java.util.Scanner` has lots of methods to get values of specific types: [`nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBoolean--), [`nextByte()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextByte--), etc.

Also, I would strongly suggest: **do not use collections of raw types**. Java has pretty good generics mechanism. So, if you are in the process of learning - [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) is good resource to start.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go through it

Comment: It was resourceful, was able to learn this using generics and typesafety for Integers

cl[0]   =  45,000
cl[1]   =  125,000
cl[2]   =  17,500
cl[3]   =  8,000
cl[4]   =  4,005
[45000, 125000, 17500, 8000, 4005]`